# Delay Notification Sound

Tags: android, audio, notifications, chat, android-notifications

I am working on a group chat app. In a scenario where there are lots of messages coming in, I would like the notification tone to re-played only after an interval.

Essentially, once notification sound happens, I want notification sound to be turned off for a certain interval (60s) . After the interval (60s) has elapsed, if a new message comes, only then the notification tone is re-played and again goes quiet for another 60s and so on. In between 60s intervals any number of messages would not trigger notification sound.

So, If I receive my first message at 0 seconds, then for 60 seconds, there will be no notification sound irrespective of number of messages I receive. After 60 seconds, notification sound will be played only on new message and will stay quiet for another 60 seconds.

How can this be implemented.

Thanks
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

In your **`Service`** that creates notifications, when the first message is received, play sound and start a **`CountDownTimer`** (with 60 seconds). Don't play sound until timer goes to zero. After timer goes zero, play sound on next notification and reset timer.